# HERE API Calculate Route - avoid anything changes router behavior

Tags: here-api

## Problem

If you choose to use `avoidArea`, `exclueCountries` or `avoidLinks` (and probably some more that I wasn't able to test) in your request router enforces `fastest` route mode.

Given is route from Poland to Germany.

Official testing client: http://refclient.ext.here.com/

First request (no avoids, no excludes, mode:`shortest`) was:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code=pxIXqdtgOSwQDXSDfjLQpw&app_id=cgZPrYfgRePXzXC3PbBp&jsonattributes=41&language=en-us&legattributes=le&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=shortest;car&routeattributes=sh&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!53.49012,18.80973&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!53.61957,12.43167
```

This resulted in a quite straightforward route like below.
[image: Route with no avoids]

If we add now any country exclusion (e.g. GBR, CHE, CZE) the route is now routed via motorways like `fastest` mode was enforced.

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code=pxIXqdtgOSwQDXSDfjLQpw&app_id=cgZPrYfgRePXzXC3PbBp&avoidseasonalclosures=false&excludecountries=CHE,GBR,CZE&jsonattributes=41&language=pl-pl&legattributes=le&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=shortest;car&routeattributes=sh,zo&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!53.49012,18.80973&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!53.61957,12.43167
```

[image]

**EDIT 1 BEGIN**

I checked out the new routing API and results are similar:

Without avoids:

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={API_KEY}=41&language=en-us&legattributes=le&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=shortest;car&routeattributes=sh&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!53.49012,18.80973&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!53.61957,12.43167
```

[image]

With avoids:

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey={API_KEY}&avoidseasonalclosures=false&excludecountries=CHE,GBR,CZE&jsonattributes=41&language=pl-pl&legattributes=le&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=shortest;car&routeattributes=sh,zo&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!53.49012,18.80973&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!53.61957,12.43167
```

[image]

On a sidenote, http://refclient.ext.here.com/ doesn't have option to test new API

**EDIT 1 END**

## Question

Why is it happening? Is it designed behavior? If not, when can we expect this to be fixed?

Comment: Hi - I'm a bit confused. Are you saying you don't want the fastest route? If so, what happens if you specify a mode? It may be that it's a default. So for example, in your first route are you sure it isn't defaulting to fastest too?

Comment: Hi! Yes API somehow defaults to fastest, despite having set mode: `shortest` and my question is why is this happening and if it wasn't by design, can HERE team fix it? It's no described in docs and it's confusing. About practicality - I don't want the fastest route, I need a consistent behavior. Motorways are tolled in many countries and you can see in the pictures, the shortest route is shorter by 200km!. Each km is a cost. 1$ on average. Users raise objections to such tracing such as "they would never send their drivers this route". Thank you for taking interest in my question @RaymonCamden

Comment: I'm digging into this internally. I notice you are using an earlier version of the API, well earlier URL. Can you migrate to route.ls.hereapi.com and an apiKey to see if it helps?

Comment: Sure I'll give it a try. I'll come back with results

Comment: Hey @RaymondCamden I updated the question with my results from new API, please take a look

Comment: I've been talking internally about this and am close to having an answer for you - sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got an answer for you from engineering. I'm rewording a bit so any mistakes/confusion blame me, not him. :)

So yes, the API here is ignoring your request to use shortest.

Quote from developer: Specifically in this case, when using "shortest" mode and requesting additional "avoids", routes more than 300km or so are not "good". It does not fall back to "fastest" mode but another mode where "fastest" route shape has more of an influence.

You mentioned wanting to avoid tolls, be aware that you can ask for that option when calling the API, so that may be a solution for you.

I hope this helps a bit, and thank you for being patient.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question!

Comment: Hey @Raymond Camden, will this behavior will be prevalent in [Fleet Telematics API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html)?

Comment: Not sure - did you try and see the same?

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it's the same. Actually I did that in **Edit 1** but forgot about it, sorry for bothering you

Comment: Not a bother at all.